# Large HTML Table with jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, html-table

I am working on a jQuery Mobile App. On one of the pages I display data in the form of a table. The table has many columns a does not fit in the page. Is there a way to get this table to display properly?

I found this code but am not really sure how to use it:

```
$('#dataContainer').scrollview();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works.

```
<div style="width:100%; overflow:scroll" >
Too large content
</div>
```